# Find an intermediate value for MOD factor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am developing an app. At 5 pm, the array resets and count starts from 0 and by the end of day there are thousands of values inside the array. There is a very simple code inside my logic. My data is inside the array `data`.

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry.time_stamp >= tsYesterday) {
        if (count % 100 == 0) {
            element = { x: new Date(entry.time_stamp), y: entry.occupied_count };
            history_slots.push(element);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

But the issue is that at 5 pm when there is just 1 element inside the array, it doesn't gets displayed because `(0-99)%100` so I want to replace 100 with something. Can I change the value of MOD Factor on the basis is array length? Please guide me if you understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the purpose of using `%` at all here? Please [edit] the question to better explain what the desired output is.

Comment: This `history_slots` is being passed in the history graph array. I am using % to avoid the noise.